# Efficiently combine several permutations of data.table in rstudio

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table containing arbitrary user_ids and a measured dependent variable:

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(user_id = round(runif(10,0,100),0), dv = round(runif(10, 0, 10),1))
```

I want to construct a new table that contains all of the sequential permutations of that table. To clarify, I want to accomplish

```
data_combined <- rbind(data[1:1, ],
                       data[1:2, ],
                       data[1:3, ],
                       ...
                       data[1:n, ])
```

for any arbitrary maximum n number of rows. The best way I've accomplished this is:

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(user_id = seq(1,10,1), dv = round(runif(10, 0, 10),1))
                   
for(n in 1:nrow(data)){
  ifelse(n > 1,
         data_combined <- rbindlist(list(data_combined,
                                         cbind(data[1:n, ], N = n))),
         data_combined <- cbind(data[1:n, ], N = n)
  )
}
```

This creates the required table and also appends a new variable that counts the number of rows added during each iteration.

Is this the most efficient means of accomplishing the task? It is a bit esoteric so I'm not sure there's a specific function to accomplish it, but I'm not sure that my solution is necessarily ideal either (particularly for larger max group sizes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're unlikely to find massive speed gains, at least not unless you have very large data. But if you avoid the `cbind` calls, you can write a shorter and not-quite-twice-as-fast version. I also include a marginally faster one. Note that I increased the sample size to 200 to provide more meaningful benchmarks.

```
library(data.table)
                   
N <- 200
data <- data.table(user_id = round(runif(N,0,100),0), dv = round(runif(N, 0, 10),1))

method1 <- function() {
  for(n in 1:nrow(data)){
    ifelse(n > 1,
           data_combined <- rbindlist(list(data_combined,
                                           cbind(data[1:n, ], N = n))),
           data_combined <- cbind(data[1:n, ], N = n)
    )
  }
  return(data_combined)
}

method2 <- function() {
  data_combined <- lapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) data.table(data[1:i], N=i))
  data_combined <- rbindlist(data_combined)
  return(data_combined)
}

method3 <- function() {
  data_combined <- list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    data_combined[[i]] <- data[1:i]
    data_combined[[i]][, N := i]
  }
  data_combined <- rbindlist(data_combined)
  return(data_combined)
}
```

Checking if the results are the same:

```
all(method1() == method2())
#> [1] TRUE
all(method2() == method3())
#> [1] TRUE
```

Benchmarking:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(method1(), method2(), method3())
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#>  method1() 131.94106 150.40669 166.28043 157.02466 165.40358 408.1812   100   c
#>  method2()  82.57354 100.94865 109.82735 106.36961 109.65404 202.5385   100  b 
#>  method3()  73.79046  90.20843  96.89102  96.14839  99.36719 193.2423   100 a
```

Comment: Thank you!

Your third method is exactly the kind of method I was looking for, which I could not quite figure out as I am still learning the data.table package. While I was also interested in a faster iteration by eliminating the 'for' loop if possible, ditching the cbind & ifelse calls were other options I was interested in for precisely this reason.